# Windows phone 8 String to WebView uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webview

How do i convert a string to System.URI. I was creating an app and when i specified the web view source with a string. I get an error saying " Cannot covert from string to System.uri "
Can someone help me.. 
Here is the sample code:

```
    case "UF":
                ActualLoad = @"https://caa80bd8e97cc4df33a976d33c14171baf481521.googledrive.com/host/0B9--dJ-__iVYMGh0ODJlbUlZeHM/UselessFacts.html";
                break;

        }

        //jokes is the name of the webview 
        // ActualLoad is a string which contains the link.
        Jokes.Source = ActualLoad;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new Uri instance:

```
  Jokes.Source = new Uri(ActualLoad, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working. See the screenshot: http://snag.gy/fJ3X3.jpg

Comment: Make sure ActualLoad is not null.

Comment: @Hunt3R it is NULL, check your screenshot again.  ActualLoad = null

Comment: It shouldn't be, Is it ignoring the switch statement?

Comment: IT Is skipping the switch statement. You were right. Thanks for your help!